# Can Dropwizard Metrics be integrated with Scalatra?

Tags: scala, dropwizard, scalatra

I try to setup a performance metrics tool with one of our new service built with Scala. I use Dropwizard Metrics since it is a popular one. The following code can't get compiled

```
@Timed
get("/greeting", operation(dummy)){
  val name: Option[String] = params.get("name")
  Ok(String.format("Hello %s", name.getOrElse(defaultName)))
}
```

and the error message is

```
[error] ... expected start of definition
[error]   get("/greeting", operation(dummy)){
[error]   ^
[error] one error found
```

Can Dropwizard Metrics be integrated with Scalatra? If yes, what is the right way to integrate?

Answer (score 0):

There is already built in support for metrics:

http://www.scalatra.org/2.4/guides/monitoring/metrics.html

About your code, it is not working with the annotation because you are not defining a method here, but invoking one.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will look into the document. Not follow the last comment though.

Comment: The document isn't correct in regarding of the library. "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-metrics" % "2.4.0-SNAPSHOT" yields a unfound dependency error. It should be "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-metrics" % "2.4.1".

Comment: Also, none of context.mountMetricsAdminServlet("/metrics-admin")
    context.mountHealthCheckServlet("/health")
    context.mountMetricsServlet("/metrics")
    context.mountThreadDumpServlet("/thread-dump")
    context.installInstrumentedFilter("/test/*") (stated in the document )are valid code.

Answer (score 0):

As of version *"org.scalatra"* *%* *"scalatra-metrics_2.11"* *%* *"2.5.0"* you can make `context.mountMetricsAdminServlet("/metrics-admin")` working by adding next import:

```
import org.scalatra.metrics.MetricsSupportExtensions.metricsSupportExtensions
```

It will implicitly run this:

```
metricsSupportExtensions(context).mountMetricsAdminServlet("/metrics-admin")
```